# How to Publish AngularCli application to plunker

Tags: angular, plunker

Recently I heard that angular has developed some integrated tools that will publish application directly to plunker. I cannot find any suitable docs for that or is there anyway else to publish angular-CLI applications in pulnker.

I need to report some bug in angular. but each time creating from scratch in plunker is a headache.

Comment: you can track here, for now, it does not support. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1147

Comment: thank you. but it will be really helpful if they implement it